# Erro no html django?

Tags: html5, python-3.x, django

Bom dia pessoal, estou com um pequeno problema para referenciar minha variável no html do django. Sou iniciante na parte web, estou tentando criar um site para um projeto, logo durante a construção do html, tentei realizar um "for" de referência a minha view.py, porém ele não encontra o texto salvo na variável "texts".

Informações adicionais

1) Estou trabalhando com Sublime Text 3.(Caso faça alguma diferença)

2) Já tenho adicionado os plugins: Django, anaconda(configurado), Css3, html5 e o ement.

Poderiam me ajudar a entender esse problema?

Segue código html:

```html
   </div>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron page-header">
    <h1>{{ title|capfirst }}</h1>
    <p> 
       {% for item in texts %}
       {{item}},
       {% endfor %}
        
    </p>
```

View.py do django:

```
# coding=utf-8

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
     texts = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
     elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
     aliqua']
context = {
    'title':'django e-commerce',
    'texts':texts
}
     return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se foi algum erro no control-c/control-v, mas do jeito que esta seu codigo não deveria nem compilar, o seu texts esta quebrando linha sem o scape para isso. Alem disso não tem sentido colocar apenas uma string na lista txts para depois acessar através de um `for`. Tente seguir os passos abaixo e veja se funciona:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    texts = ['Primeira String', 'Segunda string', 'Terceira String']
    context = { 'title':'django e-commerce', 'texts':texts }

    return render(request, 'core/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
{% for t in texts %}
    <p>{{ t }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Quando vc rodar deverá aparecer no browse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Grato Sidon... Na verdade estou digitando mesmo, porém obrigado pelo comentário vou verificar e consertar. Grato companheiro.

Comment: Se fizer o q eu "falei" vai ter o resultado desejado, sem sombra de duvida

Comment: Se a resposta solucionou, considere dar o aceite na questão.

Comment: Erdão Sidon, sim a resposta foi muito satisfatória... Mas como falei, estou iniciando minha vida no Django... Logo estava criando uma variavel para testar o uso de templates no framework. Porém ela facilitou bastante... Nada como colegas experientes. Grande abraço.

Comment: Então considere dar o aceite na resposta, clicando no sinal próximo ao número de votos. Obrigado,

Comment: Vc viu q no meu exemplo, eu tb crio uma variavel, da mesma forma que vc fez.